# Custom splash screen

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have made the splash screen from the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen):

I have created SplashActivity that extends from AppCompatActivity etc. Its works as expected.

But now I want set some animation to the splash activity and I am confused, because all that I put on the SplashActivity  is unvisible (and now I cann't be to sure that the itself SplashActivity  is visible).

Now I have deleted all excess stuff from the SplashActivity and start it as is:

```
// `MainLauncher` argument for my MainActivity is false now
[Activity(Theme = "@style/SplashTheme", NoHistory = true, MainLauncher = true)]  
public class SplashActivity : Activity                      // AppCompatActivity
{


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) // , PersistableBundle persistentState
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState); // persistentState
        this.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LPreloader);
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
    }

}
```

LPreloader.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/my_button"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Some element on Activity" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Theme in styles for the activity is:

```
  <style name="SplashTheme" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
  </style>
```

I want to see for example the `my_button` on activity, but I have nothing. More than that: I set breakpoint on the line `base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);` and its never stopped on it. I see just logo from `@drawable/splash_screen` and nothing.

If I create new Xamarin.Android project with same code - it works fine (I see the button). I cann't understand it. What is hinder to working in Xamarin.Forms project?

Comment: remove this below line from spalsh theme and try, it will work perfaclty
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>

Answer (score 1):

Remove Window background from splash theme and try it will work, as you except

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
  </style>
```